# Yii modules are not working

Tags: php, yii, module

Here i use three controller `TestController extends TestBaseController` and `TestBaseController extends AdminController`

**TestController**

```
<?php
class TestController extends TestBaseController{
    public function accessRules(){
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform following actions
                'actions'=>array('index'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
    public function actionIndex(){
        @$url = Yii::app()->getBaseUrl()."/test/index";
        //$data=array('messages'=>$postMissing,'models'=>$models);
        $data= '';
        $this->render('index',$data);
    }
}
```

**TestBaseContoller**

```
<?php
class TestBaseController extends AdminController{

    /**
    * override needed to check if its ajax, the redirect will be javascript
    */  
    public $baseURI ;

    public $themBaseUrI;

    public function init() {
        $this->baseURI = Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(false);
        $this->themBaseUrl = Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl;
        //   $this->changeURI();
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

**config/main.php**

```
'modules'=>array(
    'test'=>array(  
    ),
),
```

How to pass url for these modules..please help me...Thanks

Comment: Did you create an module? (protected/modules/test)

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand your question - answer is: controller action in a module can be accessed using the route **moduleID/controllerID/actionID**.